# Sequelize includes don't return mapping column

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have my two models `Vessel` and `User`, linked with the following:

```js
db.vessels.belongsTo(db.users, { as: "createdBy" });
db.vessels.belongsTo(db.users, { as: "lastUpdatedBy" });
```

When i run

```js
Vessel.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      as: "lastUpdatedBy",
      attributes: ["name"],
    },
    {
      model: User,
      as: "createdBy",
      attributes: ["name"],
    },
  ],
});
```

It returns the following

```
[
    {
        "id": "f3257418-626c-4c9c-a12f-72d2905ed2a3",
        "serial": "020035",
        "series": "Mk1",
        "volume": 1000,
        "permeability": "LP",
        "colour": "Natural",
        "manufactureDate": "2022-07-27T00:00:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2022-07-27T04:31:21.781Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-07-27T04:31:21.781Z",
        "createdById": "5f127ec9-f127-4d99-9a91-e9b7305d399f", // not required
        "lastUpdatedById": "5f127ec9-f127-4d99-9a91-e9b7305d399f", // not required
        "lastUpdatedBy": {
            "name": "Dan"
        },
        "createdBy": {
            "name": "Dan"
        }
    }
]
```

Why is it returning the mapping columns `createdById` and `lastUpdatedById`? I may be misreading the docs but I didn't think it should do that.

How do I go about getting Sequelize to not return `createdById` and `lastUpdatedById`?

Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't return them. Did you add the columns `createdById` and `lastUpdatedById` manually to your model? If so, there's no need, as Sequelize would've made them for you.

Comment: They aren't added manually, at first I did have the columns `createdBy` and `updatedBy` defined in the vessel model, but Sequelize complained so they are now removed

Answer (score 0):

So, creating such columns is default Sequelize bahaviour.
It's described in docs: [https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js~model#static-method-belongsTo](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-belongsTo)
Please look at **Example** section in this method and description in foreignKey option:

```
When using an object, you can add a name property to set the name of the column. Defaults to the name of target + primary key of target
```

try to use foreignKey option to pass object with your configuration like:

```
db.vessels.belongsTo(db.users, { foreignKey: {name: "createdBy" }})
db.vessels.belongsTo(db.users, { foreignKey: {name: "lastUpdatedBy" }});
```

It will create association columns for you, there is no need to use alias there.

Comment: What would be the code to retrieve from the db? Tried just removing the `as` from the `includes` but I get `SequilizeEagerLoadingError`

Comment: ```Vessel.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      attributes: ["name"],
    },
    {
      model: User,
      attributes: ["name"],
    },
  ],
});```
 Should work, just get rid of `as` in query as well, because you models are not aliased now.